Charge induced on a parallel long plates when one is earthed
Consider two Long Parallel plates at a distance 'd'. The one on the left has charge Q1 and right plate has charge Q2. Now the right plate is earthed using a conducting wire so the charge on right side of right plate is now 0. How can I find the new charge on right plate after some time?
I have a method but I am not satisfied with the explanation.
(Using the statement- When left to itself a system goes to a minimum potential energy.)
Energy = (∈E²*Volume)/2
So to minimize the energy i need to minimize the Volume in which the Electric Field is present. Thus the minimum volume will be there when charge on inner surface of right plate will be -Q1, so that the Electric Field will be only confined between the plates and all places outside will get cancelled. So Answer is -Q1 on second plate.
How do I solve this more mathematically?
Is there a way to understand it more mathematically or maybe more intuitively?
